# Resolve avahi hostnames via DNS

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, pptp, avahi

I would love to resolve avahi hostnames via DNS: 
I connect to the office VPN via PPTP but Avahi refuses to run on POINTOPOINT interfaces.

I just want to resolve avahi hostnames via the DNS configured when the PPTP link is up. I tried to do this using *pdnsd* but couldn't find a way.

Any hints?

Answer (score -1):

In 2006, it was made intentionally [blocked in source code](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/avahi/2006-February/000494.html) for two reasons.

In 2010, they had made it already configurable, so you can try your luck, but one major obstacle would be that your PP(T)P link should be bridgable, otherwise multicast packets will be prevented to enter your PPTP link on the other side where your VPN terminates onto. Read more [discussion here](https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=26587) on what kind of challenges you might face.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it's a complex problem; so I want to make it much simpler: I want to resolve hostnames via DNS (hosted at my office).
But I'm not sure how.

Answer (score -1):

You need to do two things to make this work

(a) Configure allow-point-to-point=yes on the client

(b) Install Avahi on the PPTP server and configure allow-point-to-point=yes, enable-reflector=yes

Comment: umpf. my PPTP server is a router that won't run linux.